# What code run when click on button in javascript backend

Tags: javascript, click, backend

what kind of code is run in javascript backend when i click on button
i dont means that :
var a = document.getElementById('hello');
a.click();

i means that what code in this 'click' function

Answer (score 1):

When you call `.click()` on an element, you are calling [HTMLElement.click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click).

> The HTMLElement.click() method simulates a mouse click on an element.
>
> When click() is used with supported elements (such as an `<input>`), it fires the element's click event. This event then bubbles up to elements higher in the document tree (or event chain) and fires their click events.

For example, if you had

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

and then did

```
button.click();
```

then you would see `clicked` logged.

It'll also activate anchor links if done on an anchor.

`HTMLElement.prototype.click` is implemented in *native code*, though - it's not in Javascript, it's in whatever language(s) were used by the browser designers, which is implementation-dependant.